# How to remove clone() rule in Javascript when screen width is smaller than

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been fiddling around with my navigation menu and decided to add a feature when you scroll down past a certain point the NAV slides down into viewport so that the user doesn't have to scroll back up to the top of the page to navigate. This is something that's become quite popular lately.

So I fiddled around and this javascript did the trick (note that I am not fluent with jquery at all):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".menu_wrapper").before($(".menu_wrapper").clone().addClass("shrink"));
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
    $("body").toggleClass("slidedown", ($(window).scrollTop() > 700));
});

});
```

Now I read that as ... duplicate or 'clone' (make another) .menu_wrapper element before the original + add the class .shrink to it ... AND only once we've scrolled past 700px, we'll see this duplicate NAV because of the class .slidedown

CSS:

```
.shrink { position:fixed; top:-400px; left:0; width:100%; border-top: 0px solid #35d3c3; z-index:99999}
.slidedown .shrink { top:0;}
```

Now this is working 100% and I'm stoked BUT (it's never smooth sailing is it!!!) now I've got a problem when I change my viewport to a screen width less than 767px - YES my website is responsive and this is where my NAV changes to the typical drop down (even without the javascript / effect above) by using css and javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.menu_wrapper').prepend('<div id="menu-icon">Menu</div>');
$("#menu-icon").on("click", function(){
    $("#menu").slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
});
```

My problem is that there is now a duplicate dropdown prepended NAV (1 on top of the other), like so:

---

### + MENU

---

### + MENU

The one NAV works but the other doesn't ... anyway regardless, when my media query hits 'mobile status' (below 767px) and the NAV prepends to a dropdown, this is when I DON'T want the whole slide-down-effect-clone (first jquery posted above) thing anymore. I want that rule to almost not exist or not apply when I'm below 767px screen width. How can I do this?

I've tried one of the obvious like:

```
.shrink { display:none}
.slidedown .shrink { display:none}
```

which almost seems like I've hit the jackpot leaving me only 1 prepended menu:

---

### + MENU

but nothing happens when I click on it - it doesn't slidedown and show the menu list items.

but I'm thinking like adding a rule within for the javasacript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".menu_wrapper").before($(".menu_wrapper").clone().addClass("shrink"));
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
    $("body").toggleClass("slidedown", ($(window).scrollTop() > 700));
});

});
```

that when we get below a width of 767px, we ignore the clone() function / rule etc?

I've done some googling of removeclass etc but because I'm a bonehead at javascript, I'm probably doing it all wrong.

Any help I'd appreciate it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to hide that menu based on certain viewport dimensions, why not use a media query?

```
@media all and (max-width: 766px){
    .shrink{ display: none; }
}
```

or

```
.shrink{ display: none; }

@media all and (min-width: 767px){
    .shrink{ display: block; }
}
```

(That might not be the best width values or CSS properties to use there, but that should get you started.)

Edit: If you wanted to do the entire thing in javascript, [the `matchMedia()` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia) is there for you, too.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response ... this is exactly my problem. I am using media queries as you've suggested and it's not working BUT I think my problem lies in the onpage jquery that I posted above (the whole clone() jquery) because regardless of my CSS, the jquery is still executing the clone() ... this is my assumption. I think what I really need to do is find a way to unclone the clone when I'm below a width of 767px which I think quantumwannabe is trying to say...

Answer (score 0):

If the CSS media query approach that ajm posted does not work for you, you could try only executing your code if a media query is met. The code in `handleMediaQuery()` will only run if the width is above 767px;

```
//Media query listeners
var mql = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 767px)");
mql.addListener(handleMediaQuery);
handleMediaQuery(mql);

function handleMediaQuery(mql) {
    if (mql.matches) {
        // Do stuff here that you want done when the query matches
    }
    else {
        // Do stuff here that you want done when the query does not match
    }
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Testing_media_queries for more info

Comment: Thank you for the fast response!! See my reply to AJM... with regards to the code you've given me... I'm afraid I'm clueless as to what I must do with it other than to copy and paste it (sorry my knowledge on javascript is terrible)... but when you say "will only run if the width is above 767px" - this is precisely what I think I need but ya, I wouldn't know what to do / put in place of // Do Stuff here ...

Comment: Read the MDN link that I put in the code block above. Essentially, the code creates a listener for whatever media query is put inside the `window.matchMedia` function. The `handleMediaQuery` function is a callback, that is called when the media query changes. You just put whatever code you only want to execute when the media query matches there, or call another function from within the callback.